# Initialization of objects

Tags: php

I'm trying to instanciate a class using this constructor

```
<?php
namespace Application\Model;

class FicheModel
{
    private $idFiche;
    private $mois;
    private $annee;    
    private $nbFiches;
    private $statut;
    private $commentaire;

    public function __contruct($idFiche, $mois, $annee, $nbFiches, $statut, $commentaire)
    {
        $this->setIdFiche($idFiche);
        $this->setMois($mois);
        $this->setAnnee($annee);
        $this->setNbFiches($nbFiches);
        $this->setStatut($statut);
        $this->setCommentaire($commentaire);
    }

    public function getIdFiche() {return $this->idFiche;}
    public function getMois() {return $this->mois;}
    public function getAnnee() {return $this->annee;}
    public function getNbFiches() {return $this->nbFiches;}
    public function getStatut() {return $this->statut;}
    public function getCommentaire() {return $this->commentaire;}

    public function setIdFiche($idFiche) {$this->idFiche = $idFiche;}
    public function setMois($mois) {$this->mois = $mois;}
    public function setAnnee($annee) {$this->annee = $annee;}
    public function setNbFiches($nbFiches) {$this->nbFiches = $nbFiches;}
    public function setStatut($statut) {$this->statut = $statut;}
    public function setCommentaire($commentaire) {$this->commentaire = $commentaire;}
}
?>
```

this way

```
// I've tested the value of all of the arguments of them contains a value (aren't null)
$fiche = new \Application\Model\FicheModel($refhl, $mois, $annee, $nbFiches, $statut, '');
```

Proceeding this way sets the object's arguments to null, I've used `print_r(get_object_vars($fiche)` to check that which sends back `Array()`.

How to fix that, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pls show the entire class

Comment: What's `print_object_vars()`? php.net does not have documentation for that method (although there's `get_object_vars()` which will return an array for you to iterate) `get_object_vars()` will only return accessible properties (means: no private member variables)

Comment: This is still not the whole class. Where is `setIdFiche` definition?

Comment: @user3822066 And I repeat again - this class is incomplete. There are no other methods definitions in your question

Comment: What is the result of `print_r($fiche);` command?

Comment: Did you use Java before PHP? Because using getters and setters for something that would be a `struct` in C/C++/C# is just a horrible idea.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, yes I did. But, why would that be horrible ?

Comment: If your class is just a collection of variables that _anything_ can change, and it doesn't have actual _logic_, you would use a `struct` in C/C++/C#. However, PHP and Java don't have those. But if you are allowing anything to change it, don't use method calls to do that. Just let them interact with the variables directly by making them public. Many Java design patterns (such as this one) are ones that should stay with Java. Many CS teachers I've talked with don't know what a `struct` is because Java doesn't have one.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, I'm using that because the project that I'm working on can evolve in the future and I'm just trying to set an extended architecture.

Comment: Except that if by default (with no logic) you are allowing full access to the variables, you shouldn't use getters and setters. It will still be extendable, you just won't access the variables with getters and setters, but with their actual variable name. And if you're thinking about extending the getters and setters, you'd be breaking so many design patters with that

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Using getters and setters is in no way a horrible idea. Public properties + PHP's object overloading (setting new properties on the fly) make code a lot more error prone (a simple type when assigning a property is enough to cause mysterious bugs to appear)

Comment: @Elias if you look at the correct answer, there's the problem. And it's a simple typo that PHP doesn't tell you about.

Comment: @ColeJohnson No, PHP doesn't tell you, but that's why IDEs where invented.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I was commenting on your claim that a class containing only getters and setters is a bad idea. It's not: `$foo->nmae = 'bar';` instead of `$foo->name='bar';` would create a new property. A non-existent setter is a lot easier to debug. Maintainable code is the reason why getters and setters exist. Maintainable code is one of the key requirements of _good code_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no constructor in your class.

You have in your code:

```
__contruct
```

it should be

```
__construct
     ^
```

That's why your class properties haven't been initialized with values you want

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a _simple typographical error_. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that the properties are set to `null` is wrong. [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/get_object_vars) will return an array with all accessible properties of an object. Private properties are not accessible and thus not part of the array returned by `get_object_vars`.

You can very easily check the correct values of your fields with the following code:

```
$fiche = new \Application\Model\FicheModel($refhl, $mois, $annee, $nbFiches, $statut, '');
var_dump(array(
  $fiche->getIdFiche(),
  $fiche->getMois(),
  $fiche->getAnnee(),
  $fiche->getNbFiches(),
  $fiche->getStatut(),
  $fiche->getCommentaire()));
```

Also make sure the typo `__contruct` is not in your original code.